# ConditionalOnExpression is not working on FeignClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have created a FeignClient and added ConditionalOnExpression, but after adding ConditionalOnExpression, FeignClient is not loaded and complains No qualifying bean of type MyFeignClient. It working fine if I remove ConditionalOnExpression, and the ConditionalOnExpression returns true in the other component.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${com.service}'.contains('MANISH')")
@FeignClient(name = "client", url = "${com.api-url}}")
public interface RacingMeetingFeignClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "${com.my-endpoint")
    String getRestResult();

}
```